# Redux createSelector doesn't appear to memoize results

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've been reading the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors) on `createSelector` and i'm under the impression that it's supposed to memoize the results to avoid expensive calculations. However, for some reason my `console.logs` are firing in functions that *should'nt* be firing. Curious why that is, am I doing something wrong? By the time I reach this specific component, the data *already* exists in the store in the same shape so it should be memoized.

- note: `useAppDispatch` and `useAppSelector` are the same as the defualts, they're just ts-typed in a central location.

**in my component:**

```js
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const rawTranscript = useAppSelector(selectRawTranscript);
  const parsedTranscript = useAppSelector(selectParsedTranscript);

  const parsedResult = useMemo(() => {
    // rawTranscript should be memoized ... 
    return transcriptParser(rawTranscript, undefined, 0.9);
  }, [rawTranscript]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // this also fires, I initially had the parsed result here but the same behavior happened.
    // const parsedResult = transcriptParser(rawTranscript, undefined, 0.9);
    dispatch(updateParsedTranscript(parsedResult));
  }, [dispatch, parsedResult]);
```

**in my redux slice:**

```js
// selectRawTranscript should be memoized (createSelector is used)
export const selectRawTranscript = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.transcript.rawTranscript,
  rawTranscript => rawTranscript
);

export const selectParsedTranscript = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.transcript.parsedTranscript,
  parsedTranscript => parsedTranscript
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selectors really aren't "memoizing" anything.  Any time you have a use of `createSelector` where the output selector is just `x => x`, there's no real memoization happening.  This is exactly equivalent to a plain function that is just `state => state.x` - you're just returning the field as-is.

Based on the code you've shown so far, the component will re-render any time the `state.transcript.rawTranscript` or `state.transcript.parsedTranscript` fields are updated by the reducer, and the effect will re-run every time the `state.transcript.rawTranscript` field is updated.

I'd suggest reading through [the recently updated Redux docs page on selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors) to get a better idea of when, how, and why to write memoized selector functions.

Also, having the effect *depend* on the parsed transcript, and then also dispatch an action that looks like it's *saving* the parsed value, seems a bit odd and with potential to cause extra re-renders.

Beyond that