# How can I memoize a variable derived from redux useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, reselect, react-usememo

How can I memoize my `rawTranscript` variable so it doesn't trigger the `useEffect` below which subsequently triggers the expensive `transcriptParser` function? I've been trying a lot of different approaches, but the fact that I am using a redux-hook (`useAppSelector`) to capture the data from the store means I cannot use an empty dependency useEffect for the initial mount (hooks can't be inside of useEffect). I also can't seem to wrap the `useAppSelector` with a `useMemo` either for the same reason.

Any thought's on how I can memoize the `rawTranscript` variable so it doesn't re-trigger the `useEffect`?

**error when using the redux-hook inside `useMemo`, `useEffect`, `useCallback`:**

> React Hook "useAppSelector" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

**component**

```js
const TranscriptCardController = (): JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  // how to memoize rawTranscript?
  const rawTranscript = useAppSelector(selectRawTranscript);
  const parsedTranscript = useAppSelector(selectParsedTranscript);

  useEffect(() => {
    const parsedResult = transcriptParser(rawTranscript, undefined, 0.9);
    dispatch(updateParsedTranscript(parsedResult));
  }, [dispatch, rawTranscript]);

  // ...
};
```

**selector**

```js
export const selectRawTranscript = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.transcript.rawTranscript,
  (rawTranscript): RawTranscript => rawTranscript
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no issue here if your `selectRawTranscript` function is purely selecting a value from the store, like `state => state.transcript.raw`.  Your effect will only run when the value of `rawTranscript` changes -- as it should.

If your `selectRawTranscript` function returns a new object every time (like it if it involves array mapping, etc.) then this is a problem that you can address either in the selector itself or in the component.

---

#### Memoized Selectors

The best place to fix this is by using `createSelector` to create a memoized selector.  For example:

```
import {createSelector} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const selectRawTranscript = createSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.data.someRawValue,
  (rawValue) => rawValue.map(entry => entry.data)
);
```

The second part of the selector is the "combiner" and it will only re-run when the value selected in the first part changes.  So you get a consistent object reference.

---

#### Equality Comparisons

If you want to fix this in the component, the way to do that is by including a second argument on `useAppSelector` (which I'm assuming is just a typed version of `useSelector`).

This second argument allows you to specify a [custom equality function](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) so that you have more control over when the selected data is considered to be "changed".  It's common to use a shallow equality comparison, so this is actually included in the `react-redux` package.

```
import { shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';
import { useAppSelector } from ...

const TranscriptCardController = (): JSX.Element => {
  const rawTranscript = useAppSelector(selectRawTranscript, shallowEqual);
...
```

---

Note: it's impossible for me to know whether or not you really do have a problem with undesirable changes in `rawTranscript` because you haven't included your selector function.  You might be overthinking this and it might be a non-issue.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response! I've updated my original post to include the selector I used. If there is anything let me know.

Comment: I see you posted another question where [Mark explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68883064/10431574) why createSelector doesn’t do anything here.  You’re definitely overthinking :) Your original code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a standalone `useCallback` where your dispatch will run on every `store` update but `useEffect` will only execute when the `callback` method is executed.

```
const TranscriptCardController = (): JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  // how to memoize rawTranscript?
  const rawTranscript = useAppSelector(selectRawTranscript);
  const parsedTranscript = useAppSelector(selectParsedTranscript);
  
  const callback = useCallback(() => {
    const parsedResult = transcriptParser(rawTranscript, undefined, 0.9);
    dispatch(updateParsedTranscript(parsedResult));
  }, [rawTranscript])


  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = callback()

    return unsubscribe
  }, [callback]);

  // ...
};
```

Comment: thank you for the response, it's interesting. However, I feel like it's a bit confusing and thus hard to maintain and build on. That said, it did make me think about underlying problem I have and thinking on it more, perhaps memoization isn't really appropriate for the use-case. Exploring your example however, if we unsubscribe from the callback (when we unmount) when we remount it will re-trigger the initial useCallback because rawTranscript will still be seen as a new value.

Comment: You don't have to use `unsubscribe`, I just put it for `async` callback because it can cause memory leak problems, but `useEffect` will only re-trigger if `useCallback` is triggered again.